# How can I swap a div based on a cookie using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, session, caching, cookies

I'm updating a wordpress site for a customer.  I've had to turn on server side caching because the site is so slow due to so many plugins.  There is nothing I can do about this and can't disable the plugins.

One of the plugins requires the user to enter an email to download a file.  If the plugin sees a valid email, it sets a session variable.  Then the page reloads.  If that session variable is set, the site displays a download button rather than the enter email form field and button.

Since server side caching is enabled, this functionality is lost.  So, what I want to do is set a cookie instead, then check that cookie client side, and swap the content of the div ( id="download" ).  I don't do much with Javascript and am having trouble getting this working.

I've set the cookie like this in PHP:

```
setcookie( 'show_download', 1 );
```

I've set the new content of the div ( dynamically generated ) like this:

```
setcookie( 'new_content', '<div class="btn-ss-downloads"><a target="_blank" href="/wp-content/plugins/ss-downloads/services/getfile.php?file=4v-zR6fc6f/9vaROBr/dTJd/Tg/D 0-dT.vBx">Download Series 20 Datasheet</a></div>' );
```

I've got a function to read the cookie in Javascript that I got from another post:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function readCookie(name) {
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        var nameEQ = name + "=";
        for(var i=0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length); //delete spaces
            if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
        }
        return "";
    }

</script>
```

The functionality that seems correct is to call `readCookie( 'show_download' );`.  If the value = 1, swap the content of `<div id="download"></div>` with the content stored in the `new_content` cookie.

How do I make this work in Javascript given the pieces I have presented here?  I'd like to just add a javascript function to my Wordpress header if that will work here.  It seems that I could just run this function after the page has rendered / loaded.  I'm not terribly familiar with the order of operations with the browser and javascript.  Please help.

Comment: A few semi-related tips: (1) Check out [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage#localStorage) in place of cookies. These items persist unlike session storage, and save you the hassle/bandwidth of cookies. (2) I'd absolutely avoid putting `'new_content', ...` in a cookie because it's so large. Cookies always get sent to the server in every request, though maybe you aren't making many requests.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
(<head>)
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var showDownload = localStorage.getItem("showDownload") //or readCookie()
    if (showDownload == 1) {
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("div.btn-ss-downloads").html("<a target='_blank'...</a>")
        )};
    }
</script>
(</head>)
```

See http://api.jquery.com/html/ and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage#localStorage

This uses jQuery, which you can include using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js"></script>
```

(This is one of the few times I'd advocate using jQuery for something so simple, because `$(document).ready` is so nice!)

Comment: Could you help structuring the rest of the logic? `If( show_download == 1 ) { swap html };`  Also, do I just wrap this in a `<script type="text/javascript"></script>`?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not considering AJAX?

If the requirement is to check validity of an address and then do certain server actions to display a button back, it looks like a good place to use AJAX.

```
$.post("downloader.php", { eml: mail_id })
    .done(function(data){ 
      if(data != "")
        $("div.btn-ss-downloads").html('<a href="' + data + '">Download</a>');
    });
```

This assumes the downloader.php does the necessary checks and returns the download URL. You can separate this logic (which seems to be part of the main page now) into downloader.php